# Tooltipster: dynamic ajax content: checkbox not accessible from jQuery

Tags: jquery, tooltipster

I'm using ajax to generate content with the tooltipster plugin.

The loaded data contains input fields ( checkboxes ).
The checkboxes have dynamic ID's ( fe. #imageLabelCheckBox_525_0 )

The functionBefore ( see below ) works fine.

But in the functionAfter the checkboxes are not accessible with jQuery.

For example:
`jQuery("#imageLabelCheckBox_525_0").is(':checked')` => not accessible ??

Any ideas?

```
jQuery('.clsLabelDoc').tooltipster({
  content: '...',
  animation: 'fade',
  delay: 200,
  trigger: 'click',
  contentAsHTML: true,
  contentCloning: false,
  interactive: true,
  theme: 'tooltipster-noir',
  functionBefore: function(instance, helper){
    var origin = jQuery(helper.origin);
    var initImageId = origin.attr('data-imageid');
    var initImagetype = origin.attr('data-imagetype');

    jQuery.get('ajaxGetLabelsFromUploads.php?uploadId=' + initImageId + '&imageType=' + initImagetype, function(data) {
      instance.content(data);
    });
  },
  functionAfter: function(instance, helper){
    var origin = jQuery(helper.origin);
    var initImageId = origin.attr('data-imageid');
    var initNbrOfCheckbox = origin.attr('data-nbrofcheckbox');
    jQuery("input:checkbox").each(function(){
       var theCheckbox = jQuery(this);
       console.log(theCheckbox.attr("id"));

    });


    for (ch=0;ch<initNbrOfCheckbox;ch++){
      //if (jQuery("#imageLabelCheckBox_"+initImageId+"_"+ch).is(':checked') == true){
        //if (jQuery("#imageLabelCheckBox_"+initImageId+"_"+ch).length > 0) {
          /*
          if (document.getElementById('imageLabelCheckBox_'+initImageId+'_'+ch).checked){
            //console.log('checked');
          } else {

          }
          */
        }
      }
    });
```

**Screenshot of the problem:**
[image]

[Screenshot of ajax content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGox9.png)

Comment: Why don't you try to use a class instead of id to create your element and set a new function to verify if the element is checked or not?

Comment: I tried with a class instead of id, but same problem. 
See this screenshot please [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGox9.png)